# Compilation error when using struct defined in header file using C

Tags: c, struct

I have a strange problem. I have read all the articles I could find and I think I make everything correct:

I have a struct defined in a header file `a.h`

```
typedef struct{
  int io;
} apa;
```

This files lies in a folder, lets say `src/model`

Furthermore in the root directory I have the main file in thich I include the header files as follows:

```
#include "a.h" 

int main(){
  apa X;
 return 0;
}
```

When I compile this using gcc with the `I-flag` according to `-Isrc/model` 
I get error compilation warning that says:

```
'apa' undeclared (first use in this function)
(Each undeclare identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in)
X undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I cant seem to find the problem. Help appreciated.

Comment: Works fine with me. If `a.h` could not be included, `gcc` exists with a *No such file or directory* error message.

Comment: There are probably two `a.h`files.

Comment: If you are using include guards (#ifndef <identifier> // #define <identifier> // #endif), there are two things that might lead to your problem: 1. You wrote #ifdef instead of #ifndef and 2. the <identifier> you used could be defined by the compiler.

Comment: @Abrixas2 - great insight.  I hadn't thought of that.  I wonder if OP is showing *all* of his code or just a snippet.

Comment: @user2043377 - can you please show the output of `ls -R` from your project root directory, the complete contents of `a.h`, and the entire command line you're using to build your source file?

Answer (score 0):

If the main file is in a different folder than the header file, the total path of the header file from the main file should be mentioned.

Eg)

```
#include "/src/model/a.h"
```

Comment: Putting a full path in an `#include` directive is generally a bad idea.  It makes builds more difficult to manage and maintain and hampers porting to new environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the header file as `#include "a.h"` the compiler will search for the header file first in the current directory and then int the standard library directory. In your case you have saved the header file in a directory called `src/model` and main file in a directory named `root`. So the header file is not located by the compiler. Inorder to overcome this problem you save both the header file and the main file in the same directory or give the whole path while including the header as follows.

```
#include "/src/model/a.h"
```

Comment: It says he's using the -I flag.

Answer (score -1):

If your header file is in the different folder then you need to mention the full path to the header file into main file

for Example

```
instead of just using
#include "a.h"
you have to use   
#include "path to header file/a.h"
```

Comment: OP's post mentions he's using the `-I` flag.